# Formula to get payment dates of direct debit bills

Tags: php, algorithm, formula, billing, invoice

Having a billing payment method whose bills are set up direct debit, and their installment periods may vary: 30/60/90 days, 30/45/60, 15/30/45 and so on, how can I accurately get the installment dates?

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work with for instance 30/45/60, or 15/45/75:

```
$dates = [];     

$invoiceDate = explode('-', $invoiceDate); // yyyy-mm-dd   Generation date


foreach ($installments as $i => $installment) {  // e.g.: $installment = [30, 45, 60]

    if ($installment % 30 == 0) {
        $month = round($installment / 30);

        $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $invoiceDate[1] + $month, $invoiceDate[2], $invoiceDate[0]);                    
    }
    else {

        $month = 0;
        if ($installment > 30 && count($installments) > 1) {
            $month = floor($installment / 30);
            $installment = abs($installment - ($month * 30));
        }

        $monthOffset = 30 - date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $invoiceDate[1] + $month, 1, date('Y')));

        $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $invoiceDate[1] + $month, (int)$invoiceDate[2] + (int)$installment - $monthOffset, $invoiceDate[0]);

    }




    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

With this code, if I had to bill on 2016-04-15, payments like 30/60/90 work, returning these payment dates:

> 15/05/2016
>   15/06/2016 
>   15/07/2016

However, not with payments like 15/45/75:

> 30/04/2016
>   **31**/05/2016 (should be 30) 
>   30/06/2016

nor with 30/45/60:

> 15/05/2016 
>   **31**/05/2016 (should be 30)
>   15/06/2016

If the billing was done in 2016-04-30, this payment works: 30/45/60

> 30/05/2016
>   15/06/2016
>   30/06/2016

So does 15/45/75:

> 15/05/2016 
>   15/06/2016 
>   15/07/2016

And 30/60/90:

> 30/05/2016 
>   30/06/2016 
>   30/07/2016

Any idea how to implement an algorithm that takes into account all the possibilities?

Comment: I don't think your examples even work since months aren't all 30 days?

Comment: @JonStirling I'm using a month offset to try to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

use DAteTime object to manipulate with date

```
 $periods = [ [30,60,90], 
           [30,45,60], 
           [15,30,45]];
$date =  '2016-04-15';

$d = new DateTime($date);

foreach ($periods as $ps) 
   foreach($ps as $p) {
        $t = new DateTime($d->format('Y-m-d'));  
        echo $t->modify('+'.$p.' days')->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
        unset($t);
   }
```

result

```
2016-05-15
2016-06-14
2016-07-14
2016-05-15
2016-05-30
2016-06-14
2016-04-30
2016-05-15
2016-05-30
```

Comment: good approach, but all the bills on 14th day of month should actually be on  15th. You have to consider every month as if they had the same number of days (30).

Comment: what about february?

Comment: Even in February, it should be the 15th day in this case. Basically the algorithm must return fixed days. It's mandatory so as not to confuse the customers.

Comment: why 31/05/2016 should be 30/05 but not 01/06 ?

Comment: It's something our customers want. If the first or second month is 30, it should be 30 in subsequent iterations, no matter the number of days in that month. Same for 15, and for whatever day if the invoice is generated in another day. But anyway, they will always bill on dates 15th and 30th.